# Patchwork is squishing wordy graphs, makes them unreadable

Tags: r, graph, visualization, patchwork

I'm trying to put together a few graphs, and patchwork is squishing them.

These are some word frequency graphs taken from Julie Silge comprehensive tutorial: https://juliasilge.com/blog/term-frequency-tf-idf/

These four graphs get really squished, or if I put it one above the other, stacked vertically it also looks very weird! I would appreciate some suggestions on how to fix this, I've been grappling with it for ages :(

```
library(dplyr)
library(janeaustenr)
library(tidytext)
book_words <- austen_books() %>%
unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
count(book, word, sort = TRUE) %>%
ungroup()

total_words <- book_words %>% group_by(book) %>% summarize(total = sum(n))
book_words <- left_join(book_words, total_words)
book_words <- book_words %>%
bind_tf_idf(word, book, n)
library(ggstance)
library(ggthemes)
plot_austen <- book_words %>%
arrange(desc(tf_idf)) %>%
mutate(word = factor(word, levels = rev(unique(word))))

plot_austen_gg<-ggplot(plot_austen[1:20,], aes(tf_idf, word, fill = book, alpha = tf_idf)) +
geom_barh(stat = "identity") +
labs(title = "Highest tf-idf words in Jane Austen's Novels",
y = NULL, x = "tf-idf") +
theme_tufte(base_family = "Arial", base_size = 13, ticks = FALSE) +
scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.6, 1), guide = FALSE) +
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0))

library(patchwork)

plot_austen_gg+plot_austen_gg+plot_austen_gg+plot_austen_gg
#or
plot_austen_gg/plot_austen_gg/plot_austen_gg/plot_austen_gg
```